# ¿Cómo renderizar botón de forma dinámica con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, paypal

Estoy renderizando un botón de PayPal de forma dinámica  y a veces lo hace bien y otras no.
Me gustaría saber cómo puedo hacer para  corregir esto, creo que una forma seria verificar si se renderizo de buena forma…y si no es así volver intentar hacerlo.

¿Cómo podría hacerlo o como puedo mejorar mi código?

Código:  (La funcion CreateScriptPaypal se llama desde el document ready)

```
function CreateScriptPaypal() {
    var moneyCode = $('#moneyCode').val();
    if (moneyCode !== 'USD' && moneyCode !== 'EUR')
        moneyCode = 'USD';

    var purchaseAmount = $('#purchaseAmount').val();
    console.log(moneyCode);
    var src = null;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Processor/SrcClientPaypal",
        datatype: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            src = data.SrcPaypal;
        },
        complete: function () {
            var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.src = src;
            head.appendChild(script);
            setTimeout(RenderButton, 2500, purchaseAmount);
            console.log('PAYPAL_PAYMENT_RESPONSE');
        }
    });
}

function RenderButton(purchaseAmount) {    
    paypal.Buttons({
        createOrder: function (data, actions) {
        
            var flag = true;
            var tipoCompra = $('#tipoCompra').val();
            if (tipoCompra === 'album')
                flag = ValidatedFieldAlbum(); 
            else if (tipoCompra === 'paquete')
                flag = ValidatedFieldPack();
        
            if (!flag)
                return false;

            if (!setTimeout(PaypalRequest, 1500)) {
                console.log(false);
                return false;
            } else {
                console.log('resultado desde tootuga ' + true);
            }
               
            return actions.order.create({
                purchase_units: [{
                    amount: {
                        value: purchaseAmount
                    }
                }]
            });
        },
        onApprove: function (data, actions) {
            return actions.order.capture().then(function (details) {
                // Codigo para establecer resultado de la transaccion en el servidor
                console.log(details);
                console.log(data);
                if (details.status === 'COMPLETED') {
                    PaypalPaymentResponse(data);
                    startProductsOwner();
                }

                else {
                    alert('ERROR EN PAGO');
                }
            });
        }
    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que lo que te falla es que estás intentando usar una librería que no tienes cargada desde el inicio y no consigues esperar hasta que se cargue de manera dinámica (el `setTimeout` parece un intento...)

Elimina ese `setTimeout` y espera con un listener a que el script se cargue:

```
...
complete: function () {

  var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = src;
  head.appendChild(script);

  //setTimeout(RenderButton, 2500, purchaseAmount);
  script.addEventListener('load', () = > RenderButton(purchaseAmount);

  console.log('PAYPAL_PAYMENT_RESPONSE');
}
```